# C - Process returned 139 (0x8B) Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm new in C so i tried to make a z-funtion program, but as a result of compilation, after enter any input information I have "Process returned 139 (0x8B) Segmentation fault"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char s[10001];
int main(void)
{
fgets(s, 10001,stdin);
int mas[strlen(s)];
int i, k = 0, help = 0, len = strlen(s);
for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
    if (i <= help)
    {
        printf(" i = %d,help = %d ", i,help);
        mas[i] = fmin(mas[i - k], help - i + 1);
    }
    while (i + mas[i] < len)
    {
        if (s[i + mas[i]] == s[mas[i]])
        {
            mas[i]++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (mas[i] > 0 && i + mas[i] - 1 > help)
    {
        k = i;
        help = i + mas[i] - 1;
    }
    printf("%d",mas[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input ?

Comment: `mas` isn't initialized.

Comment: aaaaa or ababa - my standard input

Comment: You are never initializing the `mas` array.

Comment: What would be the output be for the input `aaaa`?

Comment: thank you , i finally understood

Comment: 1 2 3 4 , as far as i remember

Comment: the returned type from `strlen()` has type `size_t` but the variable be assigned has type `int`.  This 'can' result in an incorrect value being placed in `len`, especially with values greater than 2gig.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un indent before every closing brace '}'.  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10001.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the function: `fmin()` expects both parameters to be of type `double` and it returns a value of type `double`  but all the parameters and the variable being assigned from the returned value are type `int` suggest using something like: mas[i] = (max[i-k] < (help-i+1))? max[i-k] : help-i+1;`

Comment: NOTE: the array `mas[]` is not initialized, but is being used in the calculation of `mas[i]`

Comment: when calling functions like: `fgets()` the code should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: I ran the posted code several times, with no seg fault events.  This strongly indicates the problem is the uninitialized values in the array `max[]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't initialized `mas` as an array. Declarations like `int array[4]` are computed during compiling, not at run-time, i.e. the value in the brackets has to be a predefined constant, not a variable. You have two options:
1) Allocate a static array that is big enough (you did this with the string `s`)
2) Use malloc() to allocate a dynamic array:

```
int* mas = (int*)malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(int);
```

Remember to free the memory allocated by malloc when it goes out of scope:

```
free(mas);
```

Comment: actually, with modern C compilers, Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) are allowed

Comment: Oh, I've been writing so much c99 developing low-level stuff that this didn't even cross my mind :D

Comment: `mas` is uninitialised. You need to initialise it after `malloc` and point `mas=NULL` after `free(mas)` to avoid dangling pointer

Answer (score 0):

Just Initialise `mas` using `memset`

`memset(mas,0,sizeof(mas));`